# What are the changes in the fontawesome package

Tags: fontawesome

I am trying to use the `fontawesome` package, however the following "alt" does not seem to produce anything.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{lc}
\toprule
Command & Icon \\
\midrule
\verb+\faCamera+ & \faCamera \\
\verb+\faCameraRetro+ & \faCameraRetro \\
\verb+\faTable+ & \faTable \\
\verb+\faFile+ & \faFile \\
\verb+\faFileAlt+ & \faFileAlt \\
\verb+\faPicture+ & \faPicture \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

The `\faFileAlt` does not produce anything. Also I've tried using `\faEnvelopeAlt` and still it does not produce anything. I'm using MacTeX / LaTeX for Mac.

There must have been some recent changes to the package, but I don't know what they are for the above macros that are causing the errors.

Comment: Are you using the appropriate TeX engine? What does the `.log` say? If the log file is unclear, you could edit your question to post the portions of it that seem most likely related to the problem.

Comment: It states undefined control sequence \verb+\faFileAlt+ & \faFileAlt \\
\verb+\faPicture+ & \faPicture \\

Comment: Those do not look like commands according to the documentation....

Comment: Hi is there a way to increase the size of the icon in LaTeX? I found some commands like fa-lg, fa-5x. However those don't seem to work. Not sure how to write the command to increase the icon size. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An [older version of `fontawesome`](https://www.tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontawesome/fontawesome.sty?revision=31020&view=markup) - version 2013/05/10 v3.1.1 - would have compiled to the following (compile with XeLaTeX):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{fontawesome}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{verbatim}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily{\FA}{FontAwesome}
% generic command to display an icon by its name
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\faicon}[1]{%
  {\FA\csname faicon@#1\endcsname}}
\makeatother

\expandafter\def\csname faicon@camera\endcsname             {\symbol{"F030}}  \def\faCamera            {{\FA\csname faicon@camera\endcsname}}
\expandafter\def\csname faicon@camera-retro\endcsname       {\symbol{"F083}}  \def\faCameraRetro       {{\FA\csname faicon@camera-retro\endcsname}}
\expandafter\def\csname faicon@table\endcsname              {\symbol{"F0CE}}  \def\faTable             {{\FA\csname faicon@table\endcsname}}
\expandafter\def\csname faicon@file\endcsname               {\symbol{"F016}}  \def\faFile              {{\FA\csname faicon@file\endcsname}}
\expandafter\def\csname faicon@file-alt\endcsname           {\symbol{"F0F6}}  \def\faFileAlt           {{\FA\csname faicon@file-alt\endcsname}}
\expandafter\def\csname faicon@picture\endcsname            {\symbol{"F03E}}  \def\faPicture           {{\FA\csname faicon@picture\endcsname}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{lc}
  \toprule
  Command & Icon \\
  \midrule
  \verb+\faCamera+ & \faCamera \\
  \verb+\faCameraRetro+ & \faCameraRetro \\
  \verb+\faTable+ & \faTable \\
  \verb+\faFile+ & \faFile \\
  \verb+\faFileAlt+ & \faFileAlt \\
  \verb+\faPicture+ & \faPicture \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

The new equivalence would be

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{verbatim}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{lc}
  \toprule
  Command & Icon \\
  \midrule
  \verb+\faCamera+ & \faCamera \\
  \verb+\faCameraRetro+ & \faCameraRetro \\
  \verb+\faTable+ & \faTable \\
  \verb+\faFileO+ & \faFileO \\
  \verb+\faFileTextO+ & \faFileTextO \\
  \verb+\faPictureO+ & \faPictureO \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

`\faPhoto` is an alias for `\faPictureO`.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I really appreciate it.

Comment: Hi is there a way to increase the size of the icon in LaTeX? I found some commands like fa-lg, fa-5x. However those don't seem to work. Not sure how to write the command to increase the icon size. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @JPaul: If you add `\usepackage{graphicx}` to your preamble you can use `\scalebox{<num>}{\faTable}` to scale `\faTable` by a factor of `<num>`. If `<num>` < 1 it'll shrink it, and if `<num>` > 1 it'll enlarge it. There is also `\resizebox{<width>}{<height>}{<stuff>}` where `<width>` and `<height>` are lengths (or `!` for default). Is this what you're looking for?

Answer (score 4):

Is that what you're after? Some names have changed since version 3:

```
\documentclass[x11names]{article}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\usepackage{array, xcolor} 
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{>{\ttfamily}ll}
    \verb+\faFileO+ & \faFileO \\[2ex]
    At 18 pt: & \fontsize{18}{22}\faFileO\\[2ex]
    \verb+\LARGE:+ & \LARGE\color{SeaGreen3} \faFileO
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: ...not with `\faPicture`.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I really appreciate it.

Comment: Hi is there a way to increase the size of the icon in LaTeX? I found some commands like fa-lg, fa-5x. However those don't seem to work. Not sure how to write the command to increase the icon size. Thanks for your help.

Comment: As the icons are open type or type 1 font files, you can use the usual font size changing commands (either the standard sizes \large, \Large, &c., or specifying numerically through the `\fontsize{mysize}{\mybaselineskip}`. Please see my updated answer.